# Current Date and Time (Java)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have separate Coloums of Date and Time in Data Base and also they are mapped according to my bean (Using Hibernate), I want to save formatted (Date and Time) i.e 17 10 2012 and 2 : 47 Pm respectively. I am having problem of how do I get formatted date and time into there respective coloums as my Data Base coloums are set to Date and Time type but Formatted Date and Time return a String. Code example will be much appriciated.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        salesOrder.setOrderDate(dateFormat.format(date));//Error:The method    setOrderDate(Date) in the type SalesOrder is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What are type types of the parameters of the methods `setDate` and `setTime` that you call on `someObject`?

Comment: I have re-posted the error with Code.

Comment: Are the methods `setOrderDate` and `setOrderDate` implemented by you? Adapt their declaration to your needings.

Comment: I am using Hibernate and my Bean is mapped to Db, I want the date and time to be in DATE type as shown in the error above.

Comment: Never pass around formatted strings, use the native types like `Date` or `Calendar`.

Comment: Ok Micheal. I am working on it.

Comment: @Hasan What do you want to achieve with `dateFormat`? Why don't just call `salesOrder.setOrderDate(date);`?

Comment: The problem is, I have separate coloums of Date and Time in Data Base and secondly I want the Date and Time to be in a certain format. Like 17 10 2012 and time 2 : 39 Pm Repectively.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert it.
Just pass `new Date()` to your entity. 
Date class contains both date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Java is telling you that setDate and setTime both take in Date objects, such as the first object you create in your code called 'now'. However you are passing them in String objects that you have created using the Date object.

You can pass the variable 'now' into your methods but none of the manipulating you do in between will have any effect on it as it is all on the Strings made from the Date and not the Date itself.